# What is the performance difference when set sequence allocate by one or more than one?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

if say there is a Java EE application sitting on this Oracle database, and due to concurrency concern(may have more than one instance working on the same db) we have to keep oracle sequence increment by 1. However there are situation to insert 5000+ records into the same table, I wonder what could be the **performance difference** between:

```
jdbctemplate.query(INSERT INTO DATA_TABLE(ID, DATA...) VALUES(global_seq.nextval, data...));
-- for each insertion
```

and

Let Java to allocate 100 (same to sequence increment by 100) so that

```
while(some_jpa_seq_variable<100){
    jdbctemplate.query("INSERT INTO DATA_TABLE(ID, DATA...) VALUES("+ ++some_jpa_seq_variable +", "+data+"...)");
}
```

In the first case, Java EE application will rely on Oracle to generate the next id by sequence, but increment by 1(defined in global_seq) and the second case is let Java to roll the sequence on behalf of Oracle

Comment: Sequences are [designed to be used concurrently,](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/schemaob.htm#CNCPT611) you should have a sensible (high) cache size for the sequence for better performance. You'd need to test to see if you could beat it with your own mechanism, but why reinvent the wheel when this facility is already proven?

Comment: @Alex Poole Thanks do you mean the (high) cache size as the cache of the database sequence?

Comment: @Neil Stockton I couldn't tell the difference with a thousand data... hence the question..

Comment: so you can't tell the difference, so you have your answer for that sample size ...

Comment: @Neil Stockton  no sir, I just have assumption, and I am looking for an answer :)

Comment: @Dreamer: Allow me to quote Donald Knuth: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil". (1974 Turing Award Lecture[1], Communications of the ACM 17 (12), (December 1974), p. 671)

Comment: You should probably worry much more about batching your inserts than the sequences.  Inserting 5000 rows one row-at-a-time is going to be very slow.

Comment: +1 for Jon's comment. Especially if you don't even use a prepared statement, which BTW makes your code open to SQL injection attacks, and will fail as soon as one of the parameters contain a single quote.